# Show external page and loading gif in div

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I can get the div to show the contents of the external page, but the loading gif won't show. Can anyone please correct my code. TIA

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="load-extmsg">blah</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load-extmsg').click(function(){
    $("#extmsg").load("blah.php", function(){
        $("#ajaxLoader1").remove();
    });
});
</script>

<div id='extmsg'><img src="/images/ajaxLoader2.gif" id="ajaxLoader1"/></div>
```

Below is the correct code after a little trial and error:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="load-extmsg">blah</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#load-extmsg').click(function(){
$("#ajaxLoader1").show();
    $.post('blah.php', function(data){
         $("#ajaxLoader1").remove();;
         $("#extmsg").append(data);
    })
});
});
</script>

<div id='extmsg'><img src="/images/ajax-loader2.gif" id="ajaxLoader1" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no issue here.

You are loading on top of the loader.

Try doing something like this instead:

```
$('#load-extmsg').click(function(){
    $("#ajaxLoader1").show();
    $.post('blah.php', function(data){
         $("#ajaxLoader1").hide();
         $("#extmsg").append(data);
    })
});
```

Add some css to hide the loading image:

```
#ajaxLoader1 {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: the image didnt show up because i forgot the '-' in the loading gif's name, but the image is always showing in the div. i want the gif to show when i click till the external page is loaded. should i put the loading gif and some javascript on the external page and not in the div on the main page ?

Comment: the loading gif is present as soon as the page loads, before i click the link. i need the gif to show onclick in the div then disappear after the external page loads into the same div. TIA

Comment: Thanx to Projapati and Neal for the solution. I needed to hide the image by default then onlcik show the image then after external page load remove the loading image

Answer (score 1):

I would also make sure that the image path is valid (sanity check)

Could you also check if the loading image (ajaxLoader2.gif) actually on the page when after the click. Just do inspect element in FireFox (w/ firebug)

Otherwise, if the image is there, I am not seeing any style issue that may make it hidden.

Thanks

Comment: You could also add another div below the image and drop the external page content to that div. That way the parent div will have the image always.

Comment: You have $("#ajaxLoader1").remove() which will remove the image after loading blah.php. Is the load happening too quickly so that you don't see the iamge?

Comment: the image didnt show up because i forgot the '-' in the loading gif's name, but the image is always showing in the div. i want the gif to show when i click till the external page is loaded. should i put the loading gif and some javascript on the external page and not in the div on the main page ?

Comment: You should set style="display:none" on the image. That way is hidden by default. Then you add $("#ajaxLoader1").show(); as the first line of the click handler. That will display the image first before loading ext page. You should be all set this. Give it a try

Comment: Thanx to Projapati and Neal for the solution. I needed to hide the image by default then onlcik show the image then after external page load remove the loading image

Comment: I use a common $.ajax() dispatcher to make ajax calls. I pass the image it to that dispatcher. Dispatcher will then show the image in beforeSend: function HandleBeforeSending() { if(id!=='') $('#'+id).show();}